# A client can trace route to a server but can a server get the trace route? How?

Tags: http, networking, routes, httpclient, trace

A client can trace route to a server but can a server get the trace route? How?

This is for HTTPClient download requests. I would like to see the path/hops taken but from the server instead of doing trace route from the client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you control the server, you can view what public IP addresses the clients are connecting from. You could then run your own traceroute/tracepath to that IP address. However, the path from your server to a client may not be the same path the packets take from the client to your server. Also, that gives you the path back to the client's public IP. The IP could actually be another router performing NAT. In that case there would technically be more hops that the traceroute/tracepath wouldn't show.